# How to redirect phpmyadmin to SSL on the default Ubuntu installation?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to redirect phpmyadmin to SSL on the default installation of an Ubuntu 12.04. I enabled `mod_rewrite` and I turned the engine on with:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

then, in `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`, I added the two lines to redirect, so it looks like this:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^/phpmyadmin https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
            php_value include_path .
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

It is not redirecting. Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try this modified config based on your original. Note that I have explicitly added `RewriteEngine On`, the `RewriteCond` checks if HTTPS is not on (as opposed to off) and the `RewriteRule` is slightly tweaked to be more flexible & explicit. Also added logic to explicitly force calls that are not to `phpmyadmin` to be plain HTTP:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^/(phpmyadmin) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule !^/(phpmyadmin) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
            php_value include_path .
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

JakeGould's answer doesn't work for me, possibly as I need to also redirect pages *inside* the /phpmyadmin directory. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/phpmyadmin
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This catches all URIs *starting* with `/phpmyadmin` and 301 redirects to HTTPS.

I've tested this with `Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)` and also [MadeWithLove's Htacess Tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).